# An inequality $37x \le 27(a+b+c)-64(ab+bc+ca)+64abc$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a, b, c, x$ be nonnegative real numbers where $x$ is the minimum and $a + b + c + x \le 1$.

Show that
$$37x \le 27(a+b+c) - 64(ab+bc+ca) + 64abc$$

Comment: Try to consider $f(y)=y^3-27y^2-64y-64$ where $y=a+b+c$.

Comment: could you give me slightly more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pqr method:

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$. Then $x \le p/3$ and $x \le 1 - p$.

We need to prove that
$$37x \le 27p - 64q + 64r.$$

Using $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ (three degree Schur), it suffices to prove that
$$37x \le 27p - 64q + 64\cdot \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$$
or
$$37x \le -\frac{64}{9}(9 - 4p)q + 27p - \frac{64}{9}p^3.$$

Using $9 - 4p > 0$ and $p^2 \ge 3q$,
it suffices to prove that
$$37x \le -\frac{64}{9}(9 - 4p)\cdot \frac{p^2}{3} + 27p - \frac{64}{9}p^3$$
or
$$37x \le \frac{64}{27}p^3 - \frac{64}{3}p^2 + 27p.$$

We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: $3/4 \le p \le 1$

Using $x \le 1 - p$, it suffices to prove that
$$37\cdot (1 - p) \le \frac{64}{27}p^3 - \frac{64}{3}p^2 + 27p$$
or
$$\frac{1}{27}(4p - 3)(16p^2 - 132p + 333) \ge 0$$
which is true.

**Case 2**: $0 \le p < 3/4$

Using $x \le p/3$,
it suffices to prove that
$$37\cdot p/3 \le \frac{64}{27}p^3 - \frac{64}{3}p^2 + 27p$$
or
$$\frac{4}{27}p(3 - 4p)(33 - 4p) \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you, River Li. Can we see that equality holds if and only if p = 3/4?

Comment: @ColinTan Also, $a = b = c = x = 0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the other situation where there is equality. From the pqr method, can we tell what is the equality condition?

Comment: @ColinTan Yes. $p = 0$, or $p = 3/4$ and $x = 1-p$, we get $a = b = c = x = 1/4$ or $a = b = c = x = 0$.

Comment: So strict inequality holds in Case 2.

Comment: @ColinTan You may change a little bit. Case 1: $3/4 < p \le 1$, Case 2: $0\le p \le 3/4$. Then Case 1 the inequality is strict, Case 2 equality case $p = 0$ or $p = 3/4$, and $x = p/3$.